# Named string format

Tags: c#, string

This questing has been asked some time ago, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010123/named-string-format-is-it-possible-c) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159017/named-string-formatting-in-c) and also [blogged about](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/01/04/fun-with-named-formats-string-parsing-and-edge-cases.aspx).

It all seemed a bit experimental at the time. So now some time afterwards, I would like to hear if you use any of the methods in production?

Answer (score 3):

I have used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322037/how-can-i-create-a-more-user-friendly-string-format-syntax/1322103#1322103).

Answer (score -2):

I think the closest you'll get is an indexed format:

```
String.Format("{0} has {1} quote types.", "C#", "1");
```